# Calling SCAN function via Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, scanning

Is it possible to call a **Scan** function via Javascript?
Or. Will HTML5's `accept="image/*;capture=camera">` work?

I want the scanner to be automatically called, and the file scanned will be attached to be uploaded

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to automatically call the scanner, and upload the scanned file.